# 'yerr' shape matches 'y' shape but throws value error

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

I am using the Spyder IDE(5.3.3) with python(3.9.13 64bit) on Ubuntu 20.04LTS. I am trying to plot errorbar by calculating the standard deviation between '5' sets of data. My x-coordinate is named 'RC_AVG', y-coordinate is named 'PMF_AVG' and, the standard deviation is named 'PMF_STD'. After storing data in these lists, I've reshaped all of them to shape (175,1) and then I am using the ax.errorbar command to plot the errorbars but python throws 'Value error': 'yerr' (shape: (175, 1)) must be a scalar or a 1D or (2, n) array-like whose shape matches 'y' (shape: (175, 1)). I am unable to understand the cause of this error and need help in understanding it. However, when I remove the reshape(175,1) from the x,y and, the error coordinates the code works fine and I get the graph. I am attaching the code below:

```
typeimport numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,5))

file_name = "bsResult-THETA83-IRUN"
result = []
for i in range(1,6):
    a = np.array(np.loadtxt(file_name+str(i)+".xvg", dtype = float,skiprows=18,max_rows=175))
    result.append(a)
result = np.array(result)
result1 = result.copy()

RC_AVG = np.mean(result1[:,:,0],axis=0).reshape(175,1) ###### x-coordinate
PMF_AVG = np.mean(result1[:,:,1],axis=0).reshape(175,1) ##### y-coordinate
PMF_STD = np.std(result1[:,:,2],axis=0).reshape(175,1) ###### error-coordinate

ax1.set_xlim(0.1,1.70)
ax1.set_xlabel("\u03B6 $(nm)$",fontweight = 'bold',fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel("G $(k_{B}T)$",fontweight = 'bold',fontsize=12)

ax1.errorbar(RC_AVG,PMF_AVG,yerr=PMF_STD,label = 'Nitrogen',color='#D32D41',linewidth=1.0,elinewidth=1.0, 
              capsize=1.1,ecolor='black',errorevery=(8))
#####################################################################
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/sps/software/yes/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/media/sps/hdd/PMF/REFERENCE/pmf-2G6X6-epswdr-wspce-k400/pmfReference.py", line 31, in <module>
    ax1.errorbar(RC_AVG,PMF_AVG,yerr=PMF_STD,label = 'Nitrogen',color='#D32D41',linewidth=1.0,elinewidth=1.0,

  File "/home/sps/software/yes/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1423, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "/home/sps/software/yes/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3588, in errorbar
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: 'yerr' (shape: (175, 1)) must be a scalar or a 1D or (2, n) array-like whose shape matches 'y' (shape: (175, 1)) here
```

I am able to get the errorbars in the plot if I remove the reshape(175,1) from the x,y and, the error coordinates as shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,5))

file_name = "bsResult-THETA83-IRUN"
result = []

for i in range(1,6):
    a = np.array(np.loadtxt(file_name+str(i)+".xvg", dtype = float,skiprows=18,max_rows=175))
    result.append(a)
result = np.array(result)
result1 = result.copy()

RC_AVG = np.mean(result1[:,:,0],axis=0)#.reshape(175,1) ----commented reshape
PMF_AVG = np.mean(result1[:,:,1],axis=0)#.reshape(175,1) ---commented reshape
PMF_STD = np.std(result1[:,:,2],axis=0)#.reshape(175,1) ----commented reshape

ax1.set_xlim(0.1,1.70)
ax1.set_xlabel("\u03B6 $(nm)$",fontweight = 'bold',fontsize=12)
ax1.set_ylabel("G $(k_{B}T)$",fontweight = 'bold',fontsize=12)

ax1.errorbar(RC_AVG,PMF_AVG,yerr=PMF_STD,label = 'Nitrogen',color='#D32D41',linewidth=1.0,elinewidth=1.0, 
              capsize=1.1,ecolor='black',errorevery=(8))
type here
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA3ly.png)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Shape `(175,1)` is 2D.  The `x`and `y``should always be 1D for `ax.errorbar()`, so shape `(175)`. `yerr` can be shape `(175)` when upper and lower error are the same, or shape `(175,2)` if you need upper and lower to be different.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was thinking (175,1) to be a 1-dimensional array.